# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 when convert uri to path

Tags: java, android, file-upload

When I try to convert a uri to a path to use to upload an image to an apis, this function returns

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ){
        path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
    }

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether you found something with your `query` or not.
Do someting like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getCount() >= 1) {
   // rest of your code
   // don't forget to check also for your next query
}
```